# String is getting added instead of getting replaced

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

`[TITLE|prefix=pref|suffix=suf] [STORENAME|prefix=s|suffix=s] [DYNAMIC|prefix=x|suffix=y|limit=10|seperator=-|random=1|reverse=1]`

I would like to replace the value of `prefix` of `TITLE` (which is `pref`) with `my text`.

This is what I have tried so far:

```js
const string = '[TITLE|prefix=pref|suffix=suf] [STORENAME|prefix=s|suffix=s] [DYNAMIC|prefix=x|suffix=y|limit=10|seperator=-|random=1|reverse=1]';

const search = 'TITLE';
const replace = 'prefix';
const value = 'my text';

const regex = new RegExp(`(\\[${search}(?:\\|[^\\][]*)?)]`, 'gi');
const result = string.replace(regex, `$1|${replace}=${value}]`);

console.log(result);
```

As you see, the value of `pref` will not be replaced, instead, I'll have `prefix=pref` + `prefix=my text`.  I don't want it twice. I just want to replace it. How can I do this?

Comment: Try ``const regex = new RegExp(`(\\[${search})(?:\\|[^\\][]*)?]`, 'gi');``, move Group 1 closing `)` after `${search}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if I use your code, I'll get `[TITLE|prefix=my text] ...`. The value of prefix will be replaced, which is good but suffix has been removed.

Comment: Right, you might consider ``const regex = new RegExp(`(\\[${search})(?:\\|[^\\][|]*)?`, 'gi');
const result = string.replace(regex, `$1|${replace}=${value}`);
``, but I think TheFourthBird's solution is better because it matches the key anywhere inside the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a positive lookbehind to assert what is on the left is `[TITLE|` followed by optionally matching any char except `]` and then match prefix.

See the support for using a [lookbehind in Javascript](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind).

```
(?<=\[TITLE\|[^\]]*prefix=)[^|\]]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QGUB9i/1)

```js
const string = '[TITLE|prefix=pref|suffix=suf] [STORENAME|prefix=s|suffix=s] [DYNAMIC|prefix=x|suffix=y|limit=10|seperator=-|random=1|reverse=1]';

const search = 'TITLE';
const replace = 'prefix';
const value = 'my text';

const regex = new RegExp(`(?<=\\[${search}\\|[^\\]]*${replace}=)[^|\\]]+`);
const result = string.replace(regex, value);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
(?<=\[.*?\|prefix=)\w+
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mDQSc3/1)**

```js
const string = '[TITLE|prefix=pref|suffix=suf] [STORENAME|prefix=s|suffix=s] [DYNAMIC|prefix=x|suffix=y|limit=10|seperator=-|random=1|reverse=1]';

const search = 'TITLE';
const replace = 'prefix';
const value = 'my text';

const regex = new RegExp(`(?<=\\[${search}\\|${replace}=)\\w+`, 'gi');
const result = string.replace(regex, value);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your suggested regex after `Try` is not the same as the one used in the code snippet. Actually, the code snippet solution is just the same as The fourth bird's one, you just modified the value pattern (made it match less chars, it won't match hyphens or dots, for example).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why that regex needs to be the same? It will change according to the search context. And the code is not the same as the others one, check the answered time first. Where do you mention, it should match hyphens or dots in question.

Comment: Because `(?<=\[.*?\|prefix=)\w+` is a **wrong** pattern for the given problem, look [here](https://regex101.com/r/LcpABa/1).